# Can Patching be done SharePoint with other application dbs hosted on your SQL Server?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching

We have a SharePoint 2013 FARM and SQL Server 2012. This being our Dev server, few other dotnet based application databases are deployed into our SP instance SQL Server for some testing purposes.

Can we proceed with patching of our SP farm? Does these DBs have any impact while running PSConfig? If so, do we need to take any special measures such as keeping those DB`s in read only more or anything suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing SharePoint patches will not have any effect on your non-SharePoint databases.  While running PSConfig the schema of the SharePoint databases will be updated.  So you can not run PSConfig if the DBs are in read only mode.

Comment: The dbs I am talking about are non SharePoint dbs, is it better to keep them in read-only mode or should be completly removed from that instance?

Comment: Nothing you do in or with SharePoint will have any effect on non-SharePoint DBs so you are safe to leave them as they are.